# Are there any popularity / usage statistics available for the Free RCS/SCM/VCS systems?

Tags: version-control, survey, popularity

Are there any surveys anywhere which report on number of projects and/or people using the assorted Free version control systems?

Also interesting is if a similar survey was one over time, to see how things have changed.

Obviously, it's hard to measure this sort of thing completely accurately, but it should still be possible to get reasonable estimates.

Since tags are annoyingly limited to five items, and I didn't want a bias towards/against any of the systems, for search purposes I'll add the following:
bazaar bzr cvs git hg mercurial rcs scm svn subversion vcs scm vcs popularity survey statistics
*update:* Very few views so far, so I'm cycling the tags to contain the main tags for each software, which might get more eyes on it. If only I could just put all the tags together!

Comment: Better tags would be IMHO 'version-control', 'survey', 'popularity', perhaps 'statistics' but I don't think it means whet you meant it to mean.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean about statistics, I've updated the tags again as you suggested.

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software#History_and_adoption

Comment: [An article from 2013](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/devprod-report-revisited-version-control-systems-in-2013/) suggests svn is still twice as popular as git.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git User's Surveys ([2006](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSurvey2006), [2007](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSurvey2007) and [2008](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSurvey2008)) did contain version about other SCMs... but this is of course biased. You can check how many people have given SCM in stack at [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net), open source software metric site, but I think you can check only current state. There are also results of [Debian Popularity Contest](http://popcon.debian.org) (popcon); you can even find some popcon graphs somewhere; here I am not sure whether one can get historical information.

Neither of those sources is a good solution, but I think it is a start...

***Added 20-05-2009:***
There is also [GNOME DVCS Survey results](http://blogs.gnome.org/newren/2009/01/03/gnome-dvcs-survey-results/) analysis (with links to raw data) on Elijah Newren’s blog (DVCS = Distributed Version Control System).

***Added 28-05-2009:***
There is [Survey on Decentralized Version Control Systems](http://www.cs.usask.ca/~bsd178/research/dvcs-survey/) by Brian de Alwis of Department of Computer Science in the University of Saskatchewan **being run** (see [this announcement](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/14179) on Mercurial and Git mailing lists).

Comment: Are there any published results on the USask survey?

Comment: @EmileCormier: Haven't heard of any... try asking them.

Comment: I can think if at least 001 reasons that little endian dates are confusing. http://xkcd.com/1179

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has [this summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities#Popularity) of projects and people on the popular version control *hosting* sites.   While this is not 1:1 to version control, and doesn't everything, I believe it does cover high-visibility projects.

- Github has 7x more projects than anything else!  However, the number is half cheating: [~40% are   gists](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/24/github-one-million/) and I suspect they count forks as separate projects (?)
- Sourceforge, then Launchpad have way more users than others.  Launchpad users include people who registered just for ubuntu bugs & translations.